# How to remove % from the string only if the % is present in first or last of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to remove the **%** character from my string if the **%** character present in the string, then it should check whether it is in the beginning or end then it should trim the value then the provide the result.

```
Eg: var str = "Value%" or "%Value" or "%Value%"
The result should be = Value.
Eg: var str="Va%ue"
The result should be =Va%ue.
Eg: var str= "Value"
The result should be = Value.
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not really worth an answer, but to get you going: `str.replace(/^%|%$/g, "")`

Comment: Thanks! it's working

Answer (score 0):

```js
str = (str[0] == '%' || str.endsWith('%')? str.replace(/%/g, '') : str);
```

Check if the string starts or ends with `%` before replacing

Comment: this will remove the % even if its in the middle if it starts with %
eg: str = '%test%test'

Answer (score 0):

Your regex basically needs to have two alternatives combined with an 'or' sign.
You use `^` to signal beginning and `$` to signal ending, then combine them with `|`.

The regex for percent lookup: `^%|%$`.

If you put that in to the `replace()` function and add the global lookup flag `g`, you can easily achieve what you're looking for:

```js
const percentLookupRegex = /^%|%$/g;

str.replace(percentLookupRegex, '');
```

Here's a live example:
https://regex101.com/r/nAK64n/2

Comment: The "'or' sign" is called an alternation in regex, and `^` and `$` are called anchors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex then you should look into the [anchors `^` and `$`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Eg.

```
str.replace(/^%/, '');
```

Will replace `%` in the beginning of the line with nothing.

An alternative approach is to use [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) and [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) and then [slice the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) appropriately:

```
if (str.startsWith('%') {
   str = str.slice(1);
}
```

Removing a `%` at the end of the string is left as an exercise for the reader

Answer (score 0):

```
str = (str.indexOf('%') === 0) ? str.substring(1) : str; // check for first character
str = (str.lastIndexOf('%') === (str.length - 1)) ? str.substring(0, str.length - 1) : str; //check for last character
```

This will only check for first and last character and remove only those